# C# SortedList with multiple keys. How do i implement a SortedList (or other struture) using 2 keys (priority and time)?

Tags: c#, priority-queue, sortedlist

I want to write a program that simulates a waiting list based on priority and arrival time. Priority takes higher precedent over arrival time. The list will contain priority, arrival time and name.I can manage one key priority, name or arrival time, name. What is the best way to combine 2 keys ?

Comment: You can use the built-in `SortedSet` and pass it your custom `IComparer<T>`

Comment: thanks Rob for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like code below.  CompareTo() method will allow you to use standard sort methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedList<PriorityTime, string> sList = new SortedList<PriorityTime, string>();

        }
    }

    public class PriorityTime : IComparable<PriorityTime>
    {
        public int priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime time { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(PriorityTime other)
        {
            if (other.priority != this.priority)
            {
                return this.priority.CompareTo(other.priority);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.time.CompareTo(other.time);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what i needed.

Comment: i like the way you coded the CompareTo method, it's very clean.